# How to play video files (working in windows media player on windows) in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: vlc, wmv

I have some movies in windows media player format. I would like to play these movies on Ubuntu, But these files are not playing in VLC on Ubuntu OS. What should I do?

Comment: have you check to see if the movies are playing in windows correctly. If that is true, then install vlc and right on the file, select vlc player.. comeback to give us feedback..

Comment: You can install additional codecs for proprietary formats: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package using `apt` or Synaptic. Just copy and paste `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`. This will also install Adobe Flash for Ubuntu.
 These packages can't be included with a fresh Ubuntu install since they are technically "proprietary" and cannot be distributed by any company besides the owner. (Not Canonical)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to play WMV files.

To install it, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```